# How to merge ASP Repeater columns

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datalist

I am using Repeater control in my website to create table row and columns data. 
Each row contain five columns

I want to merge first three columns of repeater 2nd row. Is it possible?

If so then please give me some example?

Thanks,
Salman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this as the `ItemTemplate` for your repeater. You can get a much better answer if you provide some code of what you're trying to accomplish...

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <%# If(Container.ItemIndex = 1, "<td colspan='3'>Combined Columns</td>", "<td>" & Eval("Col1") & "</td><td>" & Eval("Col2") & "</td><td>" & Eval("Col3") & "</td>")%>        
    <td><%#Eval("Col4")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("Col5")%></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```